# Android Bluetooth printer print without pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyvaluepair

i am using this code for printing:

```
public class BPrinterActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {
protected static final String TAG = "TAG";
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
private Button mScan, mPrint, mDisc;
private UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private ProgressDialog mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog;
private BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;
private BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bprinter);

    mScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Scan);
     mScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View mView) {
             mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
             if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                 Toast.makeText(BPrinterActivity.this, "Message1", 2000).show();
             } else {
                 if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                     Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                     startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                 } else {
                     ListPairedDevices();
                     Intent connectIntent = new Intent(BPrinterActivity.this,DeviceListActivity.class);
                     startActivityForResult(connectIntent,REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                 }
             }
         }
     });

     mPrint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mPrint);
     mPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View mView) {
             Thread t = new Thread() {
                 public void run() {
                     try {

                         String BILL = "";
                         BILL = "1234567812345678ABCDEFGH";
                         BILL="الرئيسية";
                         BILL = "ABCDEFGH";
                         OutputStream os = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();



                         os.write(BILL.getBytes());

                     } catch (Exception e) {
                         Log.e("Main", "Exe ", e);
                     }
                 }
             };
             t.start();
         }
     });

     mDisc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dis);
     mDisc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View mView) {
             if (mBluetoothAdapter != null)
                 mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
         }
     });

 }// onCreate

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     try {
         if (mBluetoothSocket != null)
             mBluetoothSocket.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("Tag", "Exe ", e);
     }
 }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     try {
         if (mBluetoothSocket != null)
             mBluetoothSocket.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("Tag", "Exe ", e);
     }
     setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
     finish();
 }

 public void onActivityResult(int mRequestCode, int mResultCode,Intent mDataIntent) {
     super.onActivityResult(mRequestCode, mResultCode, mDataIntent);

     switch (mRequestCode) {
     case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
         if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             Bundle mExtra = mDataIntent.getExtras();
             String mDeviceAddress = mExtra.getString("DeviceAddress");
             Log.v(TAG, "Coming incoming address " + mDeviceAddress);
             mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mDeviceAddress);
             mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Connecting...", mBluetoothDevice.getName() + " : "+ mBluetoothDevice.getAddress(), true, false);
             Thread mBlutoothConnectThread = new Thread(this);
             mBlutoothConnectThread.start();
             // pairToDevice(mBluetoothDevice); This method is replaced by
             // progress dialog with thread
         }
         break;

     case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
         if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             ListPairedDevices();
             Intent connectIntent = new Intent(BPrinterActivity.this,DeviceListActivity.class);
             startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
         } else {
             Toast.makeText(BPrinterActivity.this, "Message", 2000).show();
         }
         break;
     }
 }

 private void ListPairedDevices() {
     Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
     if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
         for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) {
             Log.v(TAG, "PairedDevices: " + mDevice.getName() + "  "+ mDevice.getAddress());
         }
     }
 }

 public void run() {
     try {
         mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
         mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
         mBluetoothSocket.connect();
         mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
     } catch (IOException eConnectException) {
         Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", eConnectException);
         closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
         return;
     }
 }

 private void closeSocket(BluetoothSocket nOpenSocket) {
     try {
         nOpenSocket.close();
         Log.d(TAG, "SocketClosed");
     } catch (IOException ex) {
         Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotCloseSocket");
     }
 }

 private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog.dismiss();
         Toast.makeText(BPrinterActivity.this, "DeviceConnected", 5000).show();
     }
 };


 public static byte intToByteArray(int value) {
     byte[] b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array();
     for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
         System.out.println("Selva  [" + k + "] = " + "0x"+ UnicodeFormatter.byteToHex(b[k]));
     }
     return b[3];
 }

 public byte[] sel(int val) {
     ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
     buffer.putInt(val);
     buffer.flip();
     return buffer.array();
 }
}
```

this code work very well but before printing this will going to scan device pairing it and then print now i have printer device address now i directly want to print without scan or paring

Comment: Actually what u want? u want to print without scanning devices??

Comment: @KinjalShah ya there is proble in 4.0.3 os to printing it will continiously ask for pairing device once we pair device yet it will ask so i want to search printer mac address and printing on that mac address without pairing

Comment: @PintuCorna I am facing problem in bluetooth printing plz help me to provide code for this..I have done the code for finding the device and pairing with it but when i go for print it is printing only blank spaces...please help me ..I already wasted so many days in it

Comment: @Manish what issue you are facing and in which language you are printing?

Comment: @pintuCorna I am facing problem in connecting socket...sometime it is connecting and sometime it is not connecting showing error "connect: Connection is not created (failed or aborted)."

Comment: @Manish which code you had use and if you had connection using BluetoothSocket then after printing you have to disconect that printer  if (mBluetoothSocket != null)                 mBluetoothSocket.close(); and in some device it' inbuilt problem of pairing issue like in tab2 4.0.3 version it always ask to pair in this type of situation we cannot do any thing

Comment: @Pintu Do you know how to implement this with wifi ?

Comment: @Ketan sorry i dont know with wifi